# Multi Dimensional vector C++

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, fstream, iostream

I'm trying to create a matrix like so

1 2 3

4 5 6

would be a 2x3 matrix. I'm trying to fill in the matrix dynamically from a text file with the following code

```
int main()
{
char c;
//Determine OS
#ifdef __unix
    cout << "linux machine \n";
    char dirinp[50] = "~/temp/coursein/p3-in.txt";
    char dirout[50] = "~/temp/fileio/p3-out.txt";
#endif
#ifdef _WIN32
    cout << "windows machine \n";
    char dirinp[50] = "C:\\temp\\coursein\\p3-in.txt";
    char dirout[50] = "C:\\temp\\coursein\\p3-out.txt";
#endif
//Open file
ifstream infile, outfile;
infile.open(dirinp);
if (!infile) 
{
    cout << "Couldn't open file";
}
infile.get(c);
int col = 0, row = 0;
while(!infile.eof())
{
    if (c == '\n')
    {
        col = col + 1;
        cout << "\ncol: " << col << endl;
    }
    //cout << c;
    if (isdigit(c)) 
    {
        //cout << "its a digit";
        int num = c - '0';
        matrix[col].push_back(num);
        cout << num << " added to matrix ";
    }
    infile.get(c);
}
```

My main thinking in this is you read the file character by character searching for the newline character. If the character is a digit (isdigit(c)==true) then push that element onto that line of the matrix. If you get to the new line character, go to the next vertical row of the matrix and start filling in the vector from left to right.

Comment: What's your question? Is there something wrong with your code? If something isn't working, consider adding your inputs and what you expect to happen, as well as what does happen. You can do this by [edit]ing your question. As it stands, your question is off-topic for lacking any kind of question.

Answer (score 0):

If matrix is

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix;
```

then what you have will almost work. Replace `col = col + 1` with

```
col = col + 1;
matrix.push_back(std::vector<int>());
```

If you want an `int **` then you can loop over `matrix` after you have exited the while loop

```
int **mat = new int[matrix.size()][matrix[0].size()];
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].size(); j++) {
        mat[i][j] = matrix[i][j];
    }
}
```